# Django's ModelForm unique_together validation

Tags: django, validation, modelform

I have a Django model that looks like this.

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    '''
    Represents a solution to a specific problem.
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "problem")
```

I use a form for adding models that looks like this:

```
class SolutionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        exclude = ['problem']
```

My problem is that the `SolutionForm` does not validate `Solution`'s `unique_together` constraint and thus, it returns an `IntegrityError` when trying to save the form. I know that I could use `validate_unique` to manually check for this but I was wondering if there's any way to catch this in the form validation and return a form error automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you set up everything correctly because the documentation about model forms syas clearly: "By default the clean() method validates the uniqueness of fields that are marked as unique, unique_together or unique_for_date|month|year on the model. " http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: can you try it without the exclude part? manually select the problem that i assume is determined by your view.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I managed to fix this without modifying the view by adding a clean method to my form:

```
class SolutionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        exclude = ['problem']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        try:
            Solution.objects.get(name=cleaned_data['name'], problem=self.problem)
        except Solution.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Solution with this Name already exists for this problem')

        # Always return cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

The only thing I need to do now in the view is to add a problem property to the form before executing `is_valid`.

Comment: Don't use a bare except clause.  This will pass even if the exception is due to the database server being hit by a meteor.  Instead, use "except Solution.DoesNotExist:".

Comment: This worked for me. Unlike OP however, my two fields were regular fields and I did not had to exclude either of the fields in the form `META`'s exclude` attribute.

Comment: One minor issue with this technique is with race conditions. The Solution object might be inserted after this check, and if it is, you will still see an IntegrityError. I think to avoid this you could just catch the error on save.

Answer (score 40):

I solved this same problem by overriding the `validate_unique()` method of the ModelForm:

```
def validate_unique(self):
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
    exclude.remove('problem') # allow checking against the missing attribute

    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError, e:
        self._update_errors(e.message_dict)
```

Now I just always make sure that the attribute not provided on the form is still available, e.g. `instance=Solution(problem=some_problem)` on the initializer.

Comment: Note that this only validates any forms for this model, while unique_together is used in the underlying database.

That means that anything that uses the model objects directly are not bound by this validation.

Answer (score 32):

As Felix says, ModelForms are supposed to check the `unique_together` constraint in their validation.

However, in your case you are actually excluding one element of that constraint from your form. I imagine this is your problem - how is the form going to check the constraint, if half of it is not even on the form?

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. So I guess that I can't get an error on the form without also including the problem field and that I'll have to manually check for this case.

Comment: Then how we can solve this problem ? We want to exclude ForeignKey field from modelform but in view store the ForeignKey in modelform because we don't give user to  access to store ForeignKey in modelform.

Answer (score 11):

the solution from @sttwister is right but can be simplified.

```
class SolutionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        exclude = ['problem']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        if Solution.objects.filter(name=cleaned_data['name'],         
                                   problem=self.problem).exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                  'Solution with this Name already exists for this problem')

        # Always return cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

As a bonus you do not retreive the object in case of duplicate but only check if it exists in the database saving a little bit of performances.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Jarmo's answer, the following seems to work nicely for me (in Django 1.3), but it's possible I've broken some corner case (there are a lot of tickets surrounding `_get_validation_exclusions`):

```
class SolutionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solution
        exclude = ['problem']

    def _get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclude = super(SolutionForm, self)._get_validation_exclusions()
        exclude.remove('problem')
        return exclude
```

I'm not sure, but this seems like a Django bug to me... but I'd have to look around the previously-reported issues.

---

Edit: I spoke too soon. Maybe what I wrote above will work in some situations, but not in mine; I ended up using Jarmo's answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this:

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SolutionForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        problem = ... # logic to find the problem instance
        solution = Solution(problem=problem) # or solution.problem = problem
        form = SolutionForm(request.POST, instance=solution)
        # the form will validate because the problem has been provided on solution instance
        if form.is_valid():
            solution = form.save()
            # redirect or return other response
    # show the form
```

Comment: The form still doesn't validate the `unique_together` constraint, probably because problem is mentioned in the `exclude` property, even though it has a valid instance

Answer (score 0):

If you want the error message to be a associated with the `name` field (and appear next to it):

```py
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    name_field = 'name'
    name = cleaned_data.get(name_field)

    if name:
        if Solution.objects.filter(name=name, problem=self.problem).exists():
            cleaned_data.pop(name_field)  # is also done by add_error
            self.add_error(name_field, _('There is already a solution with this name.'))

    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based off Django 2.1

Leave SolutionForm alone, have a save() method in Solution

```
class Solution(models.Model):
...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.clean()
      return super(Solution, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


  def clean():
      # have your custom model field checks here
      # They can raise Validation Error

      # Now this is the key to enforcing unique constraint
      self.validate_unique()
```

Calling full_clean() in save() does not work as the ValidationError will be unhandled

Answer (score 0):

I needed to exclude the `company` field in my case and add it in the view's `form_valid` function. I ended up doing the following (taking inspiration from different answers).
In my `CreateView`

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        user_company = self.request.user.profile.company
        if UnitCategory.objects.filter(code=cleaned_data['code'],
                                    company=user_company).exists():
            form.add_error('code',                           _(
                'A UnitCategory with this Code already exists for this company.'))
            return super(UnitCategoryCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        if UnitCategory.objects.filter(color=cleaned_data['color'],
                                    company=user_company).exists():
            form.add_error('color',                           _(
                'A UnitCategory with this Color already exists for this company.'))
            return super(UnitCategoryCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        form.instance.company = user_company
        return super(UnitCategoryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In my `UpdateView` I had to exclude the current instance of the object in checking if the query exist using `exclude(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])`

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        user_company = self.request.user.profile.company
        if UnitCategory.objects.filter(code=cleaned_data['code'],
                                       company=user_company).exclude(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).exists():
            form.add_error(
                'code', _('A UnitCategory with this Code already exists for this company.'))
            return super(UnitCategoryUpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        if UnitCategory.objects.filter(color=cleaned_data['color'],
                                       company=user_company).exclude(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).exists():
            form.add_error('color', _(
                'A UnitCategory with this Color already exists for this company.'))
            return super(UnitCategoryUpdateView, self).form_invalid(form)
        # Return form_valid if no errors raised
        # Add logged-in user's company as form's company field
        form.instance.company = user_company
        return super(UnitCategoryUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Not the cleanest solution I was hoping for, but thought it might benefit someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you *always* want to check the uniqueness constraint (i.e. on every ModelForm you create), you can make sure the uniqueness constraint is always validated on the model:

```
# Always check name-problem uniqueness
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    if exclude is None:
        exclude = []

    try:
        exclude.remove("problem")
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return super().validate_unique(exclude)
```

This works because the model's `validate_unique` method is called during form validation.