# Django Modelform (with excluded field)

Tags: django, validation, forms

I have a sample form:

```
class AdminDiscountForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Discount  
        exclude = ('company',)
```

the model it's pointing to is:

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_('Discount')
        verbose_name_plural=_('Discounts')
        unique_together = ('company','type')

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=DISCOUNT_CHOICES)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Discount'))
```

The form excludes the 'company' field because the user has already selected this using the UI.

i am planning on doing a:

```
company = blah
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.company = company
    obj.save()
```

The problem is that the combination of 'company' and 'type' should be unique (hence the 'unique_together'). This is enforced in the database, so django doesn't care.
I need to extend the clean() method of this form to check for uniqueness as such:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    # check for uniqueness of 'company' and 'type'
```

The problem here is that 'company' is not in there because it has been excluded.
What is the best way to raise a form validation error in this case?

-- edit
This is only for **adding** discount entries.
There's no initial instance.

Comment: Answers found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jammon's method is the one I use. To expand a bit (using your example):

models.py

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_('Discount')
        verbose_name_plural=_('Discounts')
        unique_together = ('company','type')

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=DISCOUNT_CHOICES)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Discount'))
```

forms.py

```
class AdminDiscountForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Discount  
        exclude = ('company',)
```

views.py

```
def add_discount(request, company_id=None):
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, company_id)

    discount=Discount(company=company)

    if request.method == 'post':
        form = AdminDiscountForm(request.POST, instance=discount)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Success')
    else:
        form = AdminDiscountForm(instance=company)

    context = { 'company':company,
                'form':form,}

    return render_to_response('add-discount.html', context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This works by creating an instance of your discount model, then binding your form to this instance. This instance is not saved to your db but used to bind the form. This bound form has a value for company of the bound instance. It is then sent to your template for the user to fill out. When the user submits this form, and the form is validated, the model validation check will check for uniqueness of the unique together defined in Meta.

See [**`Model Validation Docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) and [**`overriding clean for ModelForms`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-modelform-clean-method)

**edit:**

You can do a couple of things to catch non unique together entry attempts.

1. Inside your form.is_valid() you can except an Integrity Error like this:

   ```
   if request.method == 'post':
       form = AdminDiscountForm(request.POST, instance=discount)
       if form.is_valid():
           try:
               form.save()
               return HttpResponse('Success')
           except IntegrityError:
               form._errors["company"] = "some message"
               form._errors["type"] = "some message"
       else:
           ...
   ```
2. Use self.instance within the model form's clean method to check for uniqueness.

Comment: I see. I got confused with Discount(). I thought it was Discount.objects.create(). My bad. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: While this is now ok, i am still getting IntegrityError since validation on unique_together doesn't happen because one of the fields has been excluded.

Comment: dont need to. can i access the instance in the form clean() method? i'll check it out.

Comment: so basically i can access self.instance.company from within clean() to do validation. Cool. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Also, a model form instance bound to a model object will contain a self.instance attribute that gives model form methods access to that specific model instance.", ahh i see you got it. nice. edited post with one other possible method.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
discount = Discount(company = blah)
form = AdminDiscountForm(request.POST, instance=discount)
if form.is_valid():
    discount = form.save()
```

And the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) say: By default the clean() method validates the uniqueness of fields that are marked as ... `unique_together`

Comment: I should point out that this is only for *adding*. No editing at all.

Comment: That's ok. You create an instance with the default values set and then that instance takes all the other values that are in the ModelForm.

Comment: Surely i can't just create an instance with default values every time. unique_together is going to kick in at some point.