# How to access modelForms fields , which are passed as model

Tags: django, modelform

**forms.py**

```
class BandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time_from = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(8,  "08:00"),(9, "09:00"),(10, "10.00"),(11,  "11:00"),
                                           (12, "12:00"),(13, "13:00"),(14, "14:00"),(15, "15:00"),
                                           (16, "16:00"),(17, "17:00"),(18, "18:00"),(19, "19:00"),
                                           (20, "20:00"),(21, "21:00"),(22, "22:00"),(23, "23:00")])
    time_to   = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(8,  "08:00"),(9,  "09:00"),(10, "10:00"),(11, "11:00"),
                                           (12, "12:00"),(13, "13:00"),(14, "14:00"),(15, "15:00"),
                                           (16, "16:00"),(17, "17:00"),(18, "18:00"),(19, "19:00"),
                                           (20, "20:00"),(21, "21:00"),(22, "22:00"),(23, "23:00")])
    class Meta:
        model = Entry1
        exclude = ('created','date')
```

**Part of views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = BandForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            if year and month and day:
                form.date = datetime.date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
                form.save()
```

Lets say i want to do some validation in forms.py for my class Bandform

`def clean_fieldname(self): ....` ,

and usually you get passed parameters like this -- `self.cleaned_data.get('field_name')`. So if i try to fetch self.cleaned_data.get('time_from') - everythings works great. But if i try to fetch self.cleaned_data.get('date') , i get None returned .

Why?

**Answer**

[Django Modelform (with excluded field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706040/django-modelform-with-excluded-field)
The only thing which was a little unclear from the Post i provided , that you must access instance in forms.py as  self.instance.fieldname but not self.cleaned_data.get('fieldname').

Comment: In models.py i have a class Entry1 with field date= models.DateField() . If i put it auto_now_add=True it inserts date automatically and everything works. How come it doesn't exist if i insert date in view before saving the form ?

Answer (score 0):

In your exclusion:

```
exclude = ('created','date')
```

You are excluding the `date` field from being visible in the form.  This might explain why you can't access `date` in cleaned_data.  Try to remove `date` from the exclude tuple and render it in your template to see if it shows up.

Comment: Sure it works that way , as it gets with  request.POST . But if i don't exclude date i get it in the form , which a user must fill , which i dont want.  I need just set it manually , as you can see in my view.

Comment: Now that i took away date from 'excluded' fields ... I also excluded it from template by manually setting fields like {{ form.fieldname }} etc.... SO i got rid of field issue in my template .... But still it feels like `form.date = datetime.date(int(year),int(month),int(day))` doesn't assign a value to the date field, and i get only None returned.

Comment: Also if it helps ... when i try in the shell to populate the form like this : `data = {'band_title': 'hello','created':datetime.datetime(2011,3,3),'date':datetime.date(2011,3,3),'time_from':8,'time_to':9}`  - `f = BandForm(data) | f.cleaned_data`  i get only 3 parameters `{'band_title': u'hello', 'time_to': u'9', 'time_from': u'8'}`   instead of 5.  FU** i am lost :D

Comment: Can you display date in the template but set it as a hidden field while initialising the date that you want during form initialisation?