# How to avoid this dropdown combo box?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've created modelform of playlist and items like this:

```
class playlistmodel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

class itemsmodel(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(playlistmodel)
    item = models.TextField()

    def __unicode(self):
            return self.item
class playlistform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = playlistmodel

class itemsform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = itemsmodel
```

My playlist view:

```
def playlistview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = playlistform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    data = form.save(commit=False)
                    data.user = request.user
                    a = data.save()
                    return render_to_response('playlist.html', {'data': a})
    else:
            form = playlistform()
            playlistmodel.user.id = request.user.id
            return render_to_response('playlist.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've also set up with login script. If you need to create a playlist, you need to login and the problem is when I'm trying to create a playlist after logging in, it shows all the users in the dropdown combo box to select which user and enter the title of the playlist. What if I want to do to remove that useless dropdown box. It also shows for item page like selecting the playlist in the dropdown box and entering the items.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706040/django-modelform-with-excluded-field

Comment: Are you talking about in the admin or in some view you've created yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to [explicitly include or exclude what fields you want displayed to the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

You'll then have to manually update the parts of the object that you excluded before you save the object to the database. Take a look at the `commit=False` argument to the `ModelForm.save()` method as [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

For example, your code might look something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: That's fine I excluded the user field and the playlist field, but I'm getting Integrity Error when I'm creating the title of the playlist.
Exception Value: reg_playlistmodel.user_id may not be NULL

Comment: How can I defaultly set the user for the above reg_playlistmode.user_id to the currently logged in user with request.user

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the docs that tell you how you can do that.

Comment: @ Brian Neal: Thanks. But now it shows this valueError, 

Exception Type: ValueError

Exception Value: Cannot assign "<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x7f0234028f50>": "playlistmodel.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: You'll have to post your code and the traceback either here or maybe in another question.

Comment: Traceback: Local vars --- data.user = request.user