# valueError in modelforms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using modelforms for getting playlist and its items. It also contains login script. I'm trying to set the currently logged in user to the user model.
You can see this thing I've posted before
[How to avoid this dropdown combo box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763612/how-to-avoid-this-dropdown-combo-box/8765298#8765298)

```
class playlistmodel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class itemsmodel(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(playlistmodel)
    item = models.TextField()

    def __unicode(self):
        return self.item

class playlistform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = playlistmodel
        exclude = {'user'}

class itemsform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = itemsmodel
        exclude = {'playlist'}
```

Here is the playlist view:

```
def playlistview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = playlistform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.user = request.user
                data.save()
                return render_to_response('playlist.html', {'data': data})
    else:
        form = playlistform()
        return render_to_response('playlist.html', {'form': form, 'user': request.user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Playlist.html file:

https://gist.github.com/1576136

Error Page:

https://gist.github.com/1576186

But I'm getting `ValueError`:

```
Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value: Cannot assign "<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x7f0234028f50>": "playlistmodel.user" must be a "User" instance

Traceback: Local vars --- data.user = request.user
```

Here is my settings.py
https://gist.github.com/1575856

Thank you.

Comment: Just in case, verify you have the default [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) in your `settings.py`

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Try `data.user_id = request.user.id` instead.

Comment: @César I've posted the link for settings.py on my question section.

Comment: @rnk, I order to debug your application can you insert a print request.user at begin of view and before assignement? Please, post results.

Comment: @César Look at my updates on my question section. I'm getting Integrity error
reg_playlistmodel.user_id may not be NULL
Traceback: data = form.save()

Comment: @César But the output in the html file shows me the correct logged in user.

Comment: Silly test, but what type of object do you see if you were to add a print statement in your view? `data.user = request.user; print data.user, type(data.user)` . We could at least make sure you are getting a proper User model instance in your request.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old, but if anyone gets here with the same problem, the answer is that `request.user` is actually a wrapper for django's `auth.user`.
So `request.user` is a `SimpleLazyObject`, and it's purpose is avoiding unnecessary instantiation, and also implementing a simple user caching mechanism.
To access the actual user (and instantiate it, when accessing the first time), you need to do:

`auth.get_user(request)`

This will give you an instance of `auth.user`.
If you need more detail on what's going on inside, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506766/django-purpose-of-django-utils-functional-simplelazyobject).

Answer (score 0):

difficult to tell, but i would try this in your playlistview:

```
form = playlistform(request, request.POST, instance=playlistmodel)
```

maybe you can ommit the last parameter (instance=playlistmodel), because this would only be in need if you change an existing object

Hope this helps...

Comment: Seems the above syntax wont work. It is showing Attribute error. Thank YOu.

Comment: Sad :(, all i can tell is that this syntax works for me in a similiar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem, but it only arises when no user is logged in (expecting an `AnonymousUser` instance). At least when my superuser is logged in, I found no problem.

Despite I have not found a solution yet, maybe you'll find a clue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507200/1351280)

Well, now I've realised that in my case AnonymousUser should be stored as null in the db, but leave this answer to post the clue link (have no permission yet to leave comments).

Hope it helps!