# django: Purpose of django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject?

Tags: django, django-views

I ran into an issue where I assigned `request.user` to a variable called `prior_user`, then essentially authenticated the user, then checked to see if `request.user != prior_user`. I expected them not to be the same and that `prior_user` should contain `AnonymousUser. To my surprise, they were the same.

Sample code:

```
prior_user = request.user   # request object, obtained froma  view
authenticate_user(request)   # some function that authenticates
print prior_user.username != request.user.username   # returns False i.e.they are the same!
```

I then discovered prior_user actually contains an instance of django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject so I assume it is some sort of lazy lookup type thing i.e. prior_user's value isn't looked up until actually used. Looking at the source code, I cannot confirm this.

Anyone with django experience can tell me what is going on and why it is needed?

This leaves me a little shaken, because the usual assignment statement doesn't work the way I expect and what else within Django acts like this? Nor did I see this described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

So anyone with super human knowledge of django can provide some clarity?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The `auth` middleware adds a `user` attribute to `request` that is an instance of `SimpleLazyObject`. `SimpleLazyObject`, itself is a subclass of `LazyObject`. `LazyObject` is, as described by the actual code:

> A wrapper for another class that can be used to delay instantiation of the wrapped class

`SimpleLazyObject` merely sets that class (the `_wrapped` attribute on `LazyObject`) via a passed in method, in this case, `get_user`. Here's the code for that method:

```
def get_user(request):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user
```

That in itself is really just a wrapper around `auth.get_user`, that enables a sort of caching mechanism. So here's what actually is eventually run:

```
def get_user(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    try:
        user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
        backend = load_backend(backend_path)
        user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
    except KeyError:
        user = AnonymousUser()
    return user
```

So, all that's really going on here is that `request.user` is ambiguous until it's actually used for something. This is important, because it allows it to adapt depending on the *current* authentication status. If you access a property on it *before* you authenticate, it returns an instance `AnonymousUser`, but if you authenticate and then access it, it returns an instance of `User`.

Comment: I have a doubt that lazy object in django and lazy-object-proxy( https://pypi.org/project/lazy-object-proxy/ ) in python works same??

Comment: Also as you said SimpleLazyObject is subclass of LazyObject then what is the difference between the two??

Comment: @PrateekGupta : "By subclassing, you have the opportunity to intercept and alter the
    instantiation. If you don't need to do that, use SimpleLazyObject."