# request.user returns a SimpleLazyObject, how do I "wake" it?

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-contrib

I have the following method:

```
def _attempt(actor):
    if actor.__class__ != User:
        raise TypeError
```

Which is called from a view:

```
self.object.attempt(self.request.user)
```

As you can see, the _attempt method expects actor to be type `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, however the object appears to be of type `django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject`. Why is this so? And more importantly, how can I convert the `LazyObject` (which apparently is a kind of wrapper for a User object) into a `User` object?

More info on `Request.user` is available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user This documentation seems to indicate the `request.user` should be a `User` object...

======Post-edit=====

I've got the following method now:

```
def _attempt(obj, action, actor, msg): 
    actor.is_authenticated() 
    if isinstance(actor, LazyObject): 
        print type(actor)
```

I'm passing a user, however the `if` condition is still true, actor is still a `LazyObject`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

See [my answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507200/654031).

Django lazy loads `request.user` so that it can be either `User` or `AnonymousUser` depending on the authentication state. It only "wakes up" and returns the appropriate class when an attribute is accessed on it. Unfortunately, `__class__` doesn't count because that's a primitive class attribute. There's occasions where you might need to know that this is actually a `SimpleLazyObject` type, and therefore it would be wrong to proxy it on to `User` or `AnonymousUser`.

Long and short, you simply can't do this comparison as you have it. But, what are you *really* trying to achieve here? If you're trying to check if it's a `User` or `AnonymousUser`, there's `request.user.is_authenticated()` for that, for example.

As a general rule though, you shouldn't abuse duck typing. A parameter should always be a particularly type or subtype (`User` or `UserSubClass`), even though it doesn't *have* to be. Otherwise, you end up with confusing and brittle code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. Indeed, I'm trying to check if it's a User or AnonymousUser. I've got the following method now:

    `def _attempt(obj, action, actor, msg):
        actor.is_authenticated()
        if isinstance(actor, LazyObject):
            print type(actor)` 
I'm passing a user, however the if condition is still true, actor is still a LazyObject. Why is this so ?

Comment: I realize I could do a try: on actor.isauthenticated() and then catch an AttributeException, which would indicate actor has no isauthenticated method (and thus is not an User). But I'm still a bit puzzled about why the snippet of code in my previous comment isn't working.

Comment: It *is* working, in one sense; `__class__` is returning exactly what it should return, `SimpleLazyObject`, because that's what the class *is*.

Comment: If I understood your original response correctly, the SimpleLazyObject should be "woken up" into a User object when an attribute is accessed on it. So, I would have thought that calling .is_authenticated(), should have turned the object into a User. Hence my confusion at the if condition I list in the first comment being false.

Comment: (I've added the if statement I'm referring to to my original question, so it's easier to understand)

Comment: We've been speaking in simplistic terms, but in reality, request.user is *always* a `SimpleLazyObject`. The instantiated user (be it `User` or `AnonymousUser`) is stored as an attribute on it, and it merely proxies the request to most attributes on itself to attributes on the user object (`__class__` being a notable exception).

Comment: Ahh I see. So using isInstance (which I assume just looks at `__class__`) on request.user  will never work. Thank you for time.

Comment: I have created three subclasses of User.  My user types are Admin, Employee and Relatives which are derivatives of User. For login, User model is used and multitable inheritance is being used. How do I convert  request.user to one of the 3 types?

Comment: `request.user.is_authenticated` is a property, not a function.

Answer (score 22):

This should do it:

```
# handle django 1.4 pickling bug
if hasattr(user, '_wrapped') and hasattr(user, '_setup'):
    if user._wrapped.__class__ == object:
        user._setup()
    user = user._wrapped
```

I had to write this so I could add a user to the session dictionary. (SimpleLazyObjects are not picklable!)

Answer (score 11):

```
user= request.user._wrapped if hasattr(request.user,'_wrapped') else request.user
```

Then you use `user` instead of `request.user`.

This is similar to UsAaR33's answer, but a one-liner is nicer for converting the object.

Comment: It is similar but it doesn't attempt to called `_setup()` on the user object if the `_wrapped` part isn't initialised properly. I think that UsAaR33's answer is preferable for this reason.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wanting to write a failing "small" unittest for your code, you can generate a wrapped `User` and stuff it inside a request.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import RequestFactory
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject

user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
    username='jacob',
    email='jacob@…',
    password='top_secret',
)

factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.get('/')
request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: user)
```

See:

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/utils_tests/test_lazyobject.py for current tests on the Lazy Objects.
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory for latest info on the `RequestFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to others and a bit cleaner.

The python method **isinstance(instance, class)** returns if the SimpleLazyObject's contained instance is of the provided class.

```
if isinstance(request.user, User):
    user = request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this and there should be no problem:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def _attempt(actor):
    actor = deepcopy(actor)
    if actor.__class__ != User:
        raise TypeError
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what your changed code does and how it helps solve the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema of the `auth_user` table in Django -

```
id
password
last_login
is_superuser
username
last_name
email
is_staff
is_active
date_joined
first_name
```

Now if you want `id` write like -

```
req.user.id
```

and if you want `username` write like -

```
req.user.username
```