# Django: Filtering drafts by user causes error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter through a set of drafts objects in a database using the request.user variable. They are For some reason I get the error listed bellow. How can I fix this bug?

Function:

```
def posting_draft(request):
    user = request.user
    user_drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user = user)
    drafts = dict()
    for d in user_drafts:
        drafts[d.title] = d.id
    return render_to_response('posting_draft.html', {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts})
```

Error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the rest of your traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since request.user is a `SimpleLazyObject` until it is accessed. Try changing your query to the following:

```
user_drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user = user.pk)
```

Comment: Could you explain what .pk does?

Comment: It's the same as `user.id`, but will work even if you have a different field set as the `primary_key`. When you call it, it will force the `SimpleLazyObject` to become populated. It does the so that the data will only be fetched from the DB if you really need it, since DB lookups are relatively expensive.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the line:

```
user = request.user
```

Read this post for more details
[request.user returns a SimpleLazyObject, how do I "wake" it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314905/request-user-returns-a-simplelazyobject-how-do-i-wake-it)