# Django request.user Not Resolving SimpleLazyObject

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-views

I have a method in my Django app that uses a user ID to find an object.  This method is called via an AJAX call.  When logged in to a valid user account, no matter what I try, `request.user` evaluates as a `django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject` object and fails to retrieve the data I want (*SkillEntry matching query does not exist* when it absolutely does exist).  I tried the solution in [Django: Filtering drafts by user causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875737/django-filtering-drafts-by-user-causes-error/11876015#11876015) to no avail.

How can I get user to refer to an actual instance of a user object?

View code:

```
@login_required
def skill_set(request, name):
    skill = Skill.objects.get(slug=name) # Found.
    level = 0
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user.is_authenticated():
            entry = SkillEntry.objects.get(user=user.pk, skill=skill) # Not found.
            entry.level = request.POST['level']
            entry.save()
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

JavaScript client-side code:

```
function setSkill(skill, value) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "/skill/" + skill + "/set/", true);
  csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  req.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
  req.send('level=' + value);
  var elem = document.getElementById('level');
  elem.innerHTML = "My skill level is " + value + ".";
}
```

Is there perhaps something I need to set in the request to maintain the session info?  I could swear I've done something like this successfully before on a much earlier version of Django.  I'm using 1.4.3.

EDIT:

Here are the model definitions in my models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, help_text='List of additional keywords this skill should show up for in search')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Skill', null=True, blank=True, help_text='Parent skill.  Leave blank if this is a root category.')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Skill, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class SkillEntry(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill')
    level = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    last_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Skill Entries'
        ordering = ('skill__name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' knows ' + self.skill.name + ' at level ' + str(self.level)
```

Comment: Try `entry = SkillEntry.objects.get(user=user, skill=skill)` instead of using `user.pk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rohan said you need not to use `user.pk`

Change this query

```
entry = SkillEntry.objects.get(user=user.pk, skill=skill)
```

TO

```
    entry = SkillEntry.objects.get(user=user, skill=skill)
```

Still if it is not working kindly share your models.py

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  That's what I tried originally and it didn't work. Added the models to the original post.

Comment: which error u are getting does that query is returning anythig