# Extending Django User model cannot access property

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I am trying to extend the default User Model in django.

I have defined a class called Profile.

```
# code in myapp/models/profile.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        field = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        class Meta:
            app_label="myapp"
```

In my view function I invoke a method where I get an exception:

```
def my_view_function(request):
    field = get_field(request.user)
    ...

def get_field(user):
   return user.profile.field
   # also tried return user.get_profile().field with AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in settings.py set to "myapp.Profile", still does not work.
```

I get an AttributeError in my stacktrace `'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_profile'`
or `'unicode' object has no attribute 'profile'`.

When I try to concatenate the user object in get_field() with a string I get an error saying `'str' cannot concatenate with 'SimpleLazyObject'`.
I tried reading [request.user returns a SimpleLazyObject, how do I "wake" it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314905/request-user-returns-a-simplelazyobject-how-do-i-wake-it) but that did not help.

I am using middleware to ensure that the user is logged in so I am sure that the user is logged in. What is wrong with the user object? Why does it django say user object has  `'__unicode__'` type.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using when you actually call the `get_field` function? You're probably passing it something incorrectly.  Also, what version of Django are you using?  (You can tell if you don't know using `pip freeze`.)

Comment: I use precisely get_field(request.user) when calling get_field function. The name of the function is different but that should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I looked at the stack trace carefully and noticed I was passing the field value to another function which expected a user object. This led to the confusing `__unicode__` error.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'yourapp.Profile'` in your `settings.py` you should be able to call the [`get_profile()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile) method on the `User` object to get the `Profile` model (for example, `request.user.get_profile()`).

To get the actual field, you would need to call `request.user.get_profile().field`.

You should note that user profiles are deprecated as of django 1.5 in favor of [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user).

Comment: its not working. I assume request.user.get_profile() is equivalent to passing request.user to a function and calling user.get_profile() there.
Note Profile class is present in myapp/models/profile.py. But I still set AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to "myapp.Profile".

Comment: Well, what is happening when you try?

Comment: I am guessing that your middleware is somehow changing `request.user` from a `User` instance to a string (unicode).

Comment: Using this middleware: http://onecreativeblog.com/post/59051248/django-login-required-middleware

Comment: Hmm.. That middleware doesn't appear to replacing `request.user`. You should add a `print type(request.user)` at the top of your view function for debugging. That will output to the console the type of the instance. If that isn't a `User` instance, something, somewhere is replacing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21904/discussion-between-iamrohitbanga-and-dgel)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Sorry I couldn't chat- got pulled away.