# How to pass a user instance in a class-based view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to pass the user instance of the current user to a variable in a class-based view and feed it in a second step, within a python script, to a database table column defined as `author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`. Related to that column I get the following integrity error: `NOT NULL constraint failed..` From the traceback I can see that my variable `loggedUser`, which I had attributed `self.request.user`, is a `SimpleLazyObject`. 

I have found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314905/request-user-returns-a-simplelazyobject-how-do-i-wake-it) similar to mine. But it discusses the issue related to functions - I am having difficulties to adapt the answers to my case of a class-based view.


How can I pass my user instance?
Thank you!

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Data(models.Model):
    temperature = models.FloatField(max_length=5)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

### views.py

```
from . import apythonscript
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class PlotGraphView(TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        loggedUser = self.request.user
        context['plot'] = apythonscript.putDataInDB(loggedUser)
        return context
```

### apythonscript.py

```
from app.models import Data

def putDataInDB(loggedUser):
    mydata=json.loads(response)

    for line in mydata['feeds']:
    #    try:
        data_handle = Data(temperature=line['field1'], author=loggedUser,)
        data_handle.save()
    #    except:
    #        continue
```

### traceback

[link to traceback](http://dpaste.com/1EGMFHZ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [request.user returns a SimpleLazyObject, how do I "wake" it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314905/request-user-returns-a-simplelazyobject-how-do-i-wake-it)

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me - you aren't using your `Data` model anywhere. Please include the full traceback as well.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I adapted the example.

Comment: You still haven’t shown the traceback.

Comment: My bad. It is added now. Thanks!

Comment: Your traceback says the missing field is `climatelog_app_data.relative_humidity`, not the user.

Comment: Oh man! You are right. The error appeared when I was passing 'self.request.user' through a variable to the python script, but what I actually messed up at that moment was commenting out 'try and except' and then not reading carefully the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

to get the currently logged in user in Django, you can simply use, `request.user`. In CBV, `request` is a class object, so you should use `self.request` to access request data.

**example**

```
class PlotGraphView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    # your stuff

    def get_current_user(self):  # this is just a custom function, you don't 
        return self.request.user
```

So, anywhere in the `CBV`'s scope, you can access the current user by `self.request.user`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution you provided did not work for me.

Comment: I messed up at another section. 'self.request.user' worked fine.

Comment: You got the expected result ?