# Django - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'

Tags: django

I get this error after installing a component into a project running django 2.1 :

---

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'
```

---

view

```
class TrackLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user in obj.likes.all():
            obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, '1')
            obj.likes.add(user)
        return url_
```

---

Full Traceback: https://pastebin.com/FmkFKDW3

---

Thank you very much

Comment: Traceback doesn't help much. When you get the error? you can print after each line and sen how far the code goes you can use a debugger for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because

When `obj.likes.add(user)` line of code being hit, The user is not somehow authenticated, Which returns Django's default request user object, which is an instance of `SimpleLazyObject`. You can either make the view as `login_required` or you can try to check whether the user is authenticated at the point or not.

For more details on this you can follow this[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314905/request-user-returns-a-simplelazyobject-how-do-i-wake-it)