# Django: NameError User_id is not defined attempting to query user's account page

Tags: python, django

After deleting the "blog post", i would like to return back to the accounts page which is account:view.

However i faced the following error that tells me that user_id is not defined. This is a NameError, as seen in the traceback.

I tried to add in the line  `user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")`above the `account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)`  as I did in the accounts.views.py
but it ended up returning another error.

Can someone advise how I should define the user_id in this view, and perhaps how i should define the account as well in other for me to correctly return to the user's account page. Many thanks!

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "HomeFeed/views.py", line 147, in delete_blog_view
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
NameError: name 'user_id' is not defined
```

**In HomeFeed App:**
urls.py

```
app_name = 'HomeFeed'

    path('<slug>/delete/', delete_blog_view, name= "delete"),
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def delete_blog_view(request,slug):
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    #YOU WANT to check if user is authenticated. if not, you need to authenticate! redirect you to that page
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("must_authenticate")
 #querying the accounts from the Account model table   
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
#querying the blog post to be deleted by referencing to the slug
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
#deleting the blog post
    blog_post.delete()
#return redirect to the account:view page after the delete
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': account.pk }))
```

**In 'account' App:**

urls.py:

```
    path('<user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
```

views.py

```
def account_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
 context = {}
 user_id = kwargs.get("user_id")
 try:
  account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
 except:
  return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.")
 if account:
  context['id'] = account.id
  context['username'] = account.username
  context['email'] = account.email
  context['profile_image'] = account.profile_image.url
  context['BASE_URL'] = settings.BASE_URL

 return render(request, "account/account.html", context)
```

models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

 USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
 REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']


 def __str__(self):
  return self.username
```

traceback for get() error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "HomeFeed/views.py", line 151, in delete_blog_view
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': account.pk }))
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments
```

edited code:

```
def delete_blog_view(request,slug):
    context = {}
    user_id = request.user.id   
    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    #account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    blog_post.delete()
    if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == reverse("HomeFeed:main"):
        return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:main"))
    elif request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': slug }):        
        return redirect(reverse( 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': request.user.id }))
    else:   
        return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main'))
    print(request.META("HTTP_REFERER"))
```

Comment: Hi mugoma, i used your method and got a type error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'

Comment: @Mugoma ^^^^^^^

Comment: There is nowhere in the posted code  where you are using `int()` function.

Comment: You can have `user_id = request.user.id`

Comment: i tried this and got a type error: get() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Could you include the url path(s) for `delete_blog_view`?

Comment: sure i have included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `id` of the user:

**account/views.py**

```
@login_required
def delete_blog_view(request,slug):

    user = request.user
    user_id=user.id
    #This is redundant as you have the login_required decorator
    #if not user.is_authenticated:
            #return redirect("must_authenticate")

    account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)

    blog_post.delete()
     
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': account.pk }))
```

If you are using the `user_id` only for the redirect, you can have:

**account/views.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse
@login_required
def delete_blog_view(request,slug):     

    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)

    blog_post.delete()
    ## checks if the  referrer is the home page
    if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("myhomeview")):
        return redirect(reverse("myhomeview")))
    elif    request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("mydetailview")):        
        return redirect(reverse( 'account:view', kwargs={'user_id': request.user.id }))
    else:
        ## include your fallback return value. 
        return redirect(reverse("mydesiredview"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer here as to what's going wrong with your solution - [django: Purpose of django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507200/6505847)

In short, this is happening because when you make the call to the `delete_blog_view(request,slug):` function, you are not logged in as an authorized user and thus `request.user` resolves to a `SimpleLazyObject`.

Just make sure that when you are calling this function the user has been authenticated.

A wild guess: can you also try to set it to `request.user.id`  and see if that works?

If nothing works, can you describe exactly how you are invoking the `delete_blog_view()` method to help me understand better.

Comment: thanks for the input, i have edited my code with comments to explain what each line means. i believe the problem could have been because ive already called for the user in the previous line. currently i still face the problem: i get a name error that says user_ id is not defined

Comment: i cant do user = request.user.id because previously i have already called user = request.user

Comment: i also cant do user_id = request.user.id as i will get a type error: get() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @timago I will check and let you know

Comment: thanks so much and god bless you! happy new year