# django: foreign key issues when creating a model object

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a row to database, with data gathered in a form. I need to work with two foreign keys and one of them is causing the creating to fail, although I am unable to figure out why:

here is my model:

```
def upload_path(instance,file):
    file_dir = Path(file).stem
    print('usr',instance.user.id)
    path = '{}/{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.user.id,"projects",file_dir,file)

    return path


class BuildingFilesVersions(models.Model):
    version_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    building_id = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='building_id_file')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="user_file")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    modification_type = models.CharField(choices=WORK_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my view:

```
@login_required
@owner_required
def RegisterFileView(request,pk):
    form = AddBuildingFileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddBuildingFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            description = form.cleaned_data["description"]
            modification_type = form.cleaned_data["modification_type"]
            filename = form.cleaned_data["modification_type"]
            file =  request.FILES['file'].name

            BuildingFilesVersions.objects.create(building_id_id=pk,
                                                 user_id=request.user,
                                                 description=description,
                                                 modification_type=modification_type,
                                                 filename=filename,
                                                 file=file)

            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = AddBuildingFileForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'building_registration/register_file.html', context)
```

what gets me confused is that the error is `Field 'building_id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <User: Vladimir>>`  even though `pk` return the proper building_id

Can anyone see where I messed up?

Answer (score 1):

to access the id of the foreign key add a double underscore

```py
BuildingFilesVersions.objects.create(building_id=Building.objects.get(pk=pk),
                                                 user=request.user,
                                                 description=description,
                                            modification_type=modification_type,
                                                 filename=filename,
                                                 file=file)
```

- Your **user** must be **logged in** to assign him in the Model
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506766/django-purpose-of-django-utils-functional-simplelazyobject/10507200#10507200) for Similar Question

[See the Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It still won't work. doing your suggestion outputs ```BuildingFilesVersions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'building_id__id```

Comment: I made an edit , test it and let me know

Comment: It seems to be valid answer

Comment: thanks for the update, it still does not work, doing as suggested outputs the error with the user field: ```Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: omae6>>": "BuildingFilesVersions.user" must be a "Building" instance.```

Comment: and if I try with ```user = request.user.id```, the error is the following: ```Cannot assign "1": "BuildingFilesVersions.user" must be a "Building" instance```

Comment: you must be logged in. try to log in

Comment: and add a checking statement for user authentication