# Cannot assign django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject, must be user instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

What's the right way to assign a User object from django.contrib.auth.models in a view to a model object with a foreign key reference to User? Example new_contact in:

```
def index(request):
    form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_contact = form.save(commit=False)
        new_contact.user = request.user
        new_contact.save()
        # send_mail ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:template'))
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

"new_contact.user = request.user" throws error ValueError at / Cannot assign "": "Contact.user" must be a "User" instance because request.user is an object wrapper, not the actual User (which doesn't exist yet). But if I set new_contact.user = auth.get_user(request) [based on answer here: [valueError in modelforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770403/valueerror-in-modelforms) ], it returns NameError 'auth' even though I'm importing django.contrib.auth into my view. What's the right way to do this? thanks

My modelform is:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contact

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = ['name','email','company']
```

Answer (score 8):

The import statement should be:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user
```

And the actual call to `get_user()`:

```
new_contact.user = get_user(request)
```

FYI, quote from `django.contrib.auth` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L135):

```
def get_user(request):
    """
    Returns the user model instance associated with the given request session.
    If no user is retrieved an instance of `AnonymousUser` is returned.
    """
    ...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that get_user is only available in Django 1.5+.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a step here, somehow. You say the user doesn't exist yet, but that's because you don't have any code that creates it. You need to do that - it's not going to be done for you.

The best way is to subclass the existing UserCreationForm from contrib.auth.forms and add your fields to it.

Comment: He's not creating a user record, so he would not use the UserCreationForm. He's creating a contact record which has a User as a foreign key. `request.user` corresponds to the logged-in user. You either did not read the question carefully or did not understand the concept of lazy evaluation — when he says the User record does not exist yet, he means that because it is a lazily evaluated object, it exists as a wrapper to the actual object, which is supposed to be returned when needed.