# Excluding a field in a ModelForm

Tags: jquery, django

As requested I am including all my models and forms fields.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class StudentProfile(models.Model):

  student = models.OneToOneField(User)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  website = models.URLField(max_length=50)


  def __unicode__(self):
   return self.user.username

class Skills(models.Model):

   student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   tags = TaggableManager()

   def __unicode__(self):
    return self.student

class Experience(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile)

    company = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=25)


    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.student
```

ModelForm

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import StudentProfile


class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
   model = StudentProfile
       exclude = ['student']

   def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
         self._user = user
         super(StudentProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password')

    def clean_username(self):
     username = self.cleaned_data['username']

     try:
       User.objects.get(username = username)
       raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already taken"+username)

     except User.DoesNotExist:

       return username

def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', '')
    if password == '':
         raise forms.ValidationError("Password be atleast 2 characters ")

    return password
```

views.py:

```
from forms import StudentProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def editbio(request):

 if request.method == 'POST':

    student = User(username = request.user)
    basic_form = StudentProfileForm(data=request.POST, user=student)

    if basic_form.is_valid():

        info = basic_form.save(commit=False)
        info.student = request.user
        info.save()
```

I am trying to exclude 'user' from modelform so I can add the current user to it. But I keep on getting form error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>student<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I am getting post data (from the forms) through :

```
$(function editinfo(){

$(".inline-form").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
    url : "/editbio",
    type : "POST",
    dataType: "json",

    data :

        $(this).serialize(),


    success : function(json) {
            $('.result').html( 'Server Response: ' + json.server_response);
        },

    error: function(data) {
            $(".result").html("Something went wrong!");
        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

});

I have searched through many results but no success. although I have used 'exclude' in forms, I am still shown 'student' field in `print basic_form.fields`
The contents of request.POST: http://pastebin.com/eLQfTFB1

Let me know what I am doing wrong here, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the result of `print basic_form.fields`? Also, are these your complete model and form classes? If that's the case I don't see how it couldn't work, but otherwise please post the complete code.

Comment: I have edited my answer, kindly have a look. `print basic_form.fields` shows http://pastebin.com/25tPVu6F.

Comment: What Django version are you using? I can't seem to replicate the problem, can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Oh and can you post all related import statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`basic_form = StudentProfileForm(data=request.POST, user=student)`
should be
`basic_form = StudentProfileForm(request.POST)`

Edit: For posterity, the issue turned out to be a whitespace issue. Advice to fellow Python developers, set your editor to use just spaces or just tabs.

Comment: that gives a 500 error. With my Firebug showing: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Right, that's because you have overridden the init method of the form. Remove that and try just StudentProfileForm(request.POST).

Comment: error this time: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'student'

Comment: are you sure you are not passing student? Just pass request.POST: StudentProfileForm(request.POST)..

Comment: with only StudentProfileForm(request.POST), I always got form errors. As mentioned in my question.

Comment: No, you passed data=POST, not POST itself. Passing just post should work. Also beware of indentation of your `fields` it appears to be wrong.

Comment: Also, try using the shell to experiment with this. That will be better to see why it is failing. Instead of request.POST, just pass a dict in the shell. Something like: my_form = StudentProfileForm(url="myurl.com", name="My Name"); my_form.is_valid() should return True.

Comment: I have tried with and without data, got same error. I know there are many solution that give this solution but it is not working out. The indentations are fine in the actual code, it got a bit disoriented here.

Comment: It's hilarious that you downvoted me, I hope that it wasn't you because I was trying to help. Anyway, the code works, that's all: See here https://gist.github.com/ustun/8789956a9cb84cdda73b

Comment: well, I was not the one who did that. I appreciate your help here. :)  Strangely my form is giving me valid = False, from the shell. I used what your codes.

Comment: OK, good to hear :) So, my advice as I said before is to try this in the shell. If that works, the data that you are sending from jQuery might be at fault here too. In that case, put a debug line in your view code: import pdb; pdb.set_trace() . This will halt the execution at that line, then inspect request.POST to see you are getting correct value.

Comment: Hmm, just saw your comment on your shell giving False. could you paste your code on github to see if there is no indentation mistake?

Comment: Also, what's the output of my_form.errors in console?

Comment: one other issue: student = User(username = request.user) this won't work, should be student = request.user (although you are not making use of it now probably?)

Comment: my_form.error : student field is required. I am little bit suspicious about my jquery post data. here is the request.POST content--> http://pastebin.com/eLQfTFB1. I am certain there are no indentation errors, otherwise Sublime wont let me execute the file(s) in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51938/discussion-between-ustun-and-anurag619)

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.djangofoo.com/67/changing-request-post-values-querydict-immutable

try

```
...
student = User(username = request.user)
post_values = request.POST.copy()
post_values['student'] = student
basic_form = StudentProfileForm(data=post_values)
.......
```

Comment: no, it didnt't worked. I am removing student from my ModelForm, so this method will show me an error. error: <ul class="errorlist"><li>student<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: @anurag619

>no, it didnt't worked

with the same error ? (This field is required.)

student is valid ? try
`post_values['student'] = student.pk`

Comment: This could possibly work, but it is better to not resort to copy()ing the POST, since that's not the canonical way to do things.

Comment: @user3535644 - I tried a bit around your solution, it didn't worked. And I agree with ustun to someextent. My real question is why I am still being shown the 'student' field when I have not included it in the forms.?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706040/django-modelform-with-excluded-field

try
`class StudentProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

 class Meta:
       model = StudentProfile
       exclude = ('student',)
`

Comment: @anurag619 if you are being shown the student field, then something is clearly wrong, unlikely, but you may even be importing the wrong form.

Answer (score -1):

Use `exclude = ['student']` instead of `fields = ('name', 'website')`,
It should work.

`fields` is used to allow you decide which fields you want to SHOW in the template (this is necessary when you generate the form using `form.as_p` or `form.as_ul`)

But here's tricky one:

in `StudentProfileForm` form override `student` and make it not required, like this:

```
student = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

It doesn't have side effect in case you're wondering.

Comment: Using exclude is discouraged, because later you may add another field to the model, and leak that info to the form accidentally.

Comment: it's not discouraged in the django doc, because they provided it to exclude field from validation. see the doc please.

Comment: I have tried using exclude as well but still same result.

Comment: @sha256 it is discouraged: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use It is strongly recommended that you explicitly set all fields that should be edited in the form using the fields attribute.

Comment: @sha256 Failure to do so can easily lead to security problems when a form unexpectedly allows a user to set certain fields, especially when new fields are added to a model. The alternative approach would be to include all fields automatically, or blacklist only some. This fundamental approach is known to be much less secure and has led to serious exploits on major websites (e.g. GitHub).

Comment: @Anurag619 If you try to fix your problem with a declarative form field, consider using `widget=HiddenInput` so the field doesn't show in the form (though it will still show in the HTML and must be validated or overridden for security purposes).