# Django Admin: How to show and hide fields on the basis of an app?

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is the current scenario:

I have a model `Transaction` in the app "`payment`"

I want to add `paypal_xyz_field` in that model `Transaction`, once the new app `payment_paypal` is being installed.

ie: Extend `Transaction` in app `paypal` and add field `paypal_xyz_field`

What will be the approach?
If I will extend the Transaction model then I will have to show both `paypalTransaction` and `Transaction` in the admin.

In admin, I want to **show only one model "`Transaction`"** 
with `paypal_xyz_field`, `paymill_xyz_field`, `stripe_xyz_field` not `paypalTransaction`, `stripeTransaction` etc.

**Also, want to auto add/remove the field from DB/admin on the basis of apps**

```
# payment/models.py
from django.db import models

class Payment(models.Model):
    base_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# paypal/models.py
from django.db import models
from payment.models import Payment

class Payment(Payment):
    paypal_specific_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# stripe/models.py
from django.db import models
from payment.models import Payment

class Payment(Payment):
    stripe_specific_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706040/django-modelform-with-excluded-field

Answer (score -1):

add the editable attribute in model field and set it False.

```
from django.db import models

class Payment(models.Model):
    base_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```