# How to auto change db input on IntegrityError in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.7

I'm using a model form to let a user put Data into the database. This form excludes the user field so the user cannot change it himself.

```
  class Meta:
    model = Server
    exclude = ["user","name", "quirky"]
```

Instead the value of the user field will be put in after I call .save(commit=False).

```
if neuer_server_form.has_changed() and neuer_server_form.is_valid():
  neuer_server = neuer_server_form.save(commit=False)
  neuer_server.user = request.user
  neuer_server.name = slugify(neuer_server.name)
  neuer_server.save()
```

Because of that the user field is excluded from validation. Now there is a unique_together between the user field and another char field.

```
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'name',)
```

Because the user field is excluded there will be no validation for the unique_together. So when saving the instance there can be an IntegrityError.

**Where I'm stuck:**
So my first Idea was to check the db if the CharField already exists and if so just change it by adding a number and check again. But if I do this counting upwards an attacker might insert a lot of similar strings so my server has to do this checking indefinitely long.

**Possible Solutions:**
So for me there would be two acceptable solutions: Either change the CharFields value to something that definitely does not exist yet without trying a lot first. Or make the validation fail and throw the form back to the user.

**What I tried:**
I think the second would be ideal, but since I'm using model formset and cannot pass the request user to the form it's not possible for me to do that:
[Django's ModelForm unique_together validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation)

Instead I was wondering if it was possible to add self made errors to a form while looping through a formset.

Somewhat like this pseudo code:

```
for form in formset.forms:
  if form.is_valid():
    server_name = form.cleaned_data.get("name","")
    if Server.objects.get(user=request.user,name=server_name).count():
      formset.forms[form].errors += "here is my own error message"
      formset.forms[form].fields["name"].errors += "this field is wrong"
```

Any ideas how to solve that? Thank you for help if you read until here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    server = Server(user=request.user)
    form = ServerForm(request.POST, instance=server)
    if form.is_valid():
        f = form.save()
        f.name = slugify(f.name)
        f.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request,
            ' '.join([v[0].__str__() for k, v in form.errors.items()]))
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. This will only give an info through the message system but not use the forms error functions right (e.g. pointing out which field is wrong)?

Comment: The output of that message is the specific error (no field name). If you want to show which field is having an error you can modify it. As you can see, there is k & v there. Why not test it for you to see.