# Validate Uniqueness Fields in Django Class Based View

Tags: django

I need to exclude the 'user' field in the form as 'user' is the loggedin user who will add the model. After reading through all Django forms documentation and referring to the answer here [Django's ModelForm unique_together validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation?lq=1)

My django views.py still reports error where 'user' is the loggined user

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/flavor/add_flavor/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'user'
```

Could anyone please point out the error in my code?

models.py

```
class Flavor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='flavors', verbose_name=_('user'))

    # Attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('name'), help_text=_('Enter the flavor name'))
    date_created = models.DateField(_("date created"), default=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Flavor')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Flavors')
        ordering = ('name', 'user')
        unique_together = ('user', 'name')
```

forms.py

```
class FlavorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Flavor
        # Never use exclude keyword which involves Massive Assignment Risk
        fields = ('name', 'date_created')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # set the user as an attribute of the form which is more robust
        # Always pop user from kwargs before calling super()
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(FlavorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        '''
        To verify the uniqueness by the unique_together fields
        '''
        cleaned_data = super(FlavorForm, self).clean()

        if Flavor.objects.filter(name=cleaned_data.get('name',''), user=self.user).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_('You have already added a flavor with this name'), code='invalid')

        # Always return cleaned data
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
class FlavorCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Flavor
    form_class = FlavorForm
    template_name = 'flavor/add_flavor.html'
    view_name = 'add_flavor'
    success_url = reverse_lazy(view_name)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        '''
        This injects form with keyword arguments.
        '''
        kwargs = super(FlavorCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        #Update the kwargs with the user_id
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # process cleaned data
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've carefully defined `get_form_kwargs` to provide the user kwarg. But then for some reason you've overridden `post`; your version instantiates the form directly, ignoring the helper methods.

There is rarely a reason to override `post` in CBVs, and certainly not in your case. Remove that whole method.

(Note, this has nothing to do with checking uniqueness.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for answering my questions. :) I have spent several days on this. I did what you said, the exception disappeared. However, how shall it verify that one user does not add the same Flavor again through the form? That is, since the 'user' field is excluded from the FlavorForm, how shall the unique_together in the model Flavor be verified?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking; that is what you are explicitly doing in `clean`, using the `user` kwarg you passed in when instantiating.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the post method and override the clean method in FlavorForm to gaurantee the uniqueness.